# prove 'every metric space is not complete'

Tags: real-analysis

problem :
prove 'every metric space is not complete'

problem in real-analysis. i'dont think solution direction.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The real line is a metric and complete.

Comment: @JackyChong OP must mean not every metric space is complete?

Comment: @qbert I agree. I just want he/she to be aware of the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the space $(0,1)$ with the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. What is the limit of the sequence
$$
\frac{1}{n}
$$
Is it Cauchy?

Comment: it is cauchy. but the limit of 1/n is 0 and that is not on space (0,1). so incomplete?

Comment: Precisely. Worth adding that the sequence is contained in the space

Comment: @2no certainly! Good luck